# Extjs Progressbar in span/div is not correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, extjs

I want to render component progress-bar in my span and insert it in `text/tooltip/cell` etc.
Then I render progressbar in body:

```
            Ext.create("Ext.ProgressBar", {
            renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
            value: chartCase.key / 100,
            width: 100
        });
```

Style for `"x-progress-text"` taking the width of component (`100px` in this case), so it is center-justified.

Then I render it in element:

```
        var span = $("<span>").attr("id", this.getId()).css("float", position);
        Ext.create("Ext.ProgressBar", {
            renderTo: span[0],
            value: chartCase.key / 100,
            width: 100
        });
```

Style `"width"` of `x-progress-text` disappears, and text `"value%"` pressed to the left.
How can I solve this problem without forcing setting style for class `".x-progress-text"`?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we want to render extjs widget in costum DOM-element, necessary use option "renderTo" to **exist** DOM-element in DOM-tree.

For example:

```
var span = $("<span>").attr("id", this.getId());
$(span[0]).appendTo("exist-element");
Ext.create("Ext.ProgressBar", {
    renderTo: $("#" + id)[0],
    value: chartCase.key / 100,
    width: 100
});
```